# Inputing to text file

Tags: c++, input, passwords

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int would;
    string pass;
    cout << "Password Manager v.1" << endl << endl;
    cout << "What's the secret?" << endl;
    cin >> pass;
    if(pass == "youcantknowsorry"){
        cout << "Access granted." << endl << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to add a new password (1) or view your passwords? (2)" << endl;
        cin >> would;
        if(would == 1){
            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open ("example.txt");
            myfile << "NewPassword" << endl; <--- HOW CAN I MAKE THAT INPUT?
            myfile.close();
        }
        if(would == 2){
            cout << "Your passwords will open in a text file.";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to write a password manager for myself. I have successfully created, opened, and written to a file using a `cout`-like method. However, I need the user to input information and for it to be saved in the file.

Comment: `trying to write a password manager for myself` -- please, please don't do that.  Try using an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume this is just about reading input and writing to a file, instead of managing passwords in a plain text file.
You have

```
int would;
cin >> would;
```

and

```
string pass;
cin >> pass;
```

So, you already know how to read input from a user. 
Similarly, you can read the password from the user, and stream it to the file:

```
string password;
cin >> password;
myfile << password << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this piece of code inside the `if` statement:

```
cin >> would;
if (would == 1)
{
    std::cin >> pass;
    std::ofstream("example.txt") << pass << std::endl;
}
```